# Is there a way I can add hair manually?

Tags: hair

Is there a way I can add hair to my mesh manually plotting it one by one?  By using the particle system, it adds hair to the entire mesh and lets you adjust but that's not really what I'm looking for.

I just want one piece of hair I can have control over like I would a mesh.  Here's my failed attempts at making hair a mesh.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a particle system to an object and change its type to "Hair" one more mode appears in the VIEW 3D modes (like Object mode, Sculpt mode, Edit mode, etc) - it is called Particle Edit mode. Select it and you will find many options allowing you to manually edit hair, including deleting, adding and editing them one by one.

Comment: Thanks! I see the option!  Now I'm just playing with it.  Does hair have the same control as meshes?  You can add physics, and materials to it ?  Is it common for artist to make hair using regular meshes or is it just a bad decision?

Comment: 1. You can add physics if you turn on Hair Dynamics in Particles settings. 2. You can add material in Particles Render tab. 3. It depends on what you are going to do with it. If you want to render them from the Blender you may not replace particles with meshes, just switch Strand to Strip in main Render Preferences Hair tab (for Eevee). You can control the visual shape of each hair-particle in particles settings. If you need to export it, you will have to replace hair with meshes and after editing convert particles to objects from modifiers tab, but dynamics may work not like you may expect.

Comment: I see.  So if I want this in unreal engine, it would be a problem.